# Eclipse 4.3.1 projects on Ubuntu 13.10 not working

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse 4.3.1 on Ubuntu 13.10, each project name was signed with a warning mark in Eclipse 4.3.1 and cannot work, but they are good in Ubuntu 13.04 and Win7, I also tried to  new a Java project, the same problem! Can someone kindly let me know how to solve!Thanks!

Comment: Look in the `Problems` view for messages describing the problems.

Comment: first,I typed "java -version" and it showed
“java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)”
second, I unzip eclipse-rcp-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz for the IDE!
Everthing is ok in Ubuntu 13.04, I cannot figure the problem out!

Answer (score 0):

After trying over and over again, I finally found that's because of the installation way of JDK, I installed JDK with "sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer" at first, that made every RCP/RAP project name signed with a warning mark! weird!
It's solved after using "-vm /home/david/MyApps/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java" instead!